# Pagination with select menu and buttons discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

[Something similar to dank memer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4pOy.png) I've been trying on how can we achieve where we can make a select menu for selecting categories and buttons to navigate through pages of those categories, the content in each category is an array. If someone could guide me, that'd be great!
I have these two array's

```js
const animals = ["Aardvark","Albatross","Alligator","Alpaca","Ant","Anteater","Antelope","Ape","Armadillo","Donkey","Baboon","Badger","Barracuda","Bat","Bear","Beaver","Bee","Bison","Boar","Buffalo","Butterfly","Camel"]

const tests = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7"]
```

So what I'm looking for is on how do I make the `animal` and `tests` to show in a select menu, and on selecting the `animal` category the animal array should be divided into pages with let's say 15 items per page, and user can navigate through them through buttons as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4pOy.png)
Similarly if user selects the `tests` array, the array contents should divide into pages with 15 elements per page and a button to navigate through those pages

Comment: I have a similar function in one of my open-source bots. You can find my code [here](https://github.com/KK-Designs/COOL-BOI-BOT/blob/master/commands/general/help.js "COOL-BOI-BOT/commands/general/help.js"). *Note: don't try and steal my entire bots code and call it yours. My bot is verified, so people will know yours is fake.*

Comment: @K.KDesgins I checked out your bot, but I couldn't find a select menu in the help command. So I'm not sure what you're talking about

Comment: This is too much code to analyze, can you try to remove some of the code so it's more clear where you're having an issue?